# Setting a character uneditable in a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

Is there a way, if so how, to set a single character within a FormattedJTextField as uneditable? I am trying to format a JTextField for currency and have read quite a few articles such as [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), though it doesn't seem to clarify what I am trying to achieve.

What I am trying to create is a JTextField which will always have the "£" sign within it and will allow the user to enter there chosen price. As a result of this, I thought maybe a way to accomplish this was to the the "£" as uneditable whereas the rest of the JTextField can be edited.

An example:

```
categoryB = new JLabel("Category B: ",JLabel.CENTER);
centerP.add(categoryB);
categoryBText = new JTextField("");
centerP.add(categoryBText);
contentP.add(centerP);
setPriceFrame.setVisible(true);
```

When the GUI is opened, I want `categoryBText`to always start with a "£" and is not removable from the JTextField.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Solution:

```
try {
   MaskFormatter catA£ = new MaskFormatter("£###.##");
   catA£.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
   categoryAText = new JFormattedTextField(catA£);
   centerP.add(categoryAText);
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: Try installing a [MaskFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) on a JFormattedTextField.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!